# Gmail accounts are being falsely indicated as non-existent

Tags: gmail

One of my remote employees has been trying to email me for two days. She emailed me without a problem last week, but this week she is getting an error message that says my Gmail email address does not exist.

Specifically, the error message says

Address not found. Your message wasn't delivered to [my Gmail email address] because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.

Her email address is white listed with me, and like I said - everything worked fine last week. Then this morning, I received the same message about a Gmail email address from a client I was emailing with important information about her account. I emailed her several times over the weekend without any problem. So whatever happened with that outage on Monday has created problems with the Gmail email accounts being recognized.

This is negatively impacting my business. Does anyone have a solution for this? Because I really can't afford this right now.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Have you already searched the official [Gmail Help Center](https://support.google.com/mail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Getting - Address not found - Using their emails as always - Suddenly getting Addy not found](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/89021478?hl=en) by Somnath, Diamond Product Expert:

> This error was reported as a fallout following the two Google service outages. You may need to wait for a period of time before this issue is resolved for you. I shall check if there are any updates on this topic and post if there is any other relevant information.

In the meantime send your feedback to Google. This could be done from the Gmail web app by clicking the ? (help) button then Send feedback.